# Java inheritance - Spring Boot conditional @GeneratedValue annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, inheritance, annotations

I have a Java Spring Boot project where I have inheritance with a class called `Base.java` with a field like this one:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String id
```

Then, I have some other intermediate classes extending from that one.

The problem is I have a couple of classes where I don't want the `@GeneratedValue` annotation, cause ID will be generated with another mechanisms.

Is there any way where I can extend from Base and, depending on any field or any method, apply the `@GeneratedValue` annotation into `id` field?

At the moment I have only though a `BaseWithoutGenerated` class and replicate the inheritance schema, but I think more elegant solutions might exist.

Comment: What is the usage of `@Generated` ? I guess  you mean `@GeneratedValue` ?

Comment: I would have 2 base classes. RealBase containing genuinely common fields (ie not the Id field) and  BaseWithGeneratedId extends RealBase. Then you decide where to put your other classes. Sadly, I don’t think anything more elegant that that is possible.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean @GeneratedValue, from javax.persistence, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two subclasses for entities with ids. One for ids that are auto-generated and one for custom ids. Using `@MappedSuperclass` will allow spring to map only the superclass to your DB objects as current classes are not mapped to any table by themselves:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GeneratedIdEntity implements IdEntityInterface {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdEntity implements IdEntityInterface {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Now, use any one of them to your respective entities and apply common business logic to both of them using the common `IdEntityInterface`